# Libreoffice: format field yyyymmdd to date

Tags: libreoffice-calc, date-time, text-formatting

How can I format a field value like 20140226 to 2014-02-26 in LibreOffice? If I use the format cell option I get strange values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following custom format code should work:

> `####-##-##`

[image]

Please notice that this won't result in a "real" date value - it's the same integer value as before, only differently formatted. If you want to "translate" the number "`20140226`" into a date value, you should apply the following formula:

> `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1;"####-##-##"))`

*(assuming A1 holds a numeric value like "20140226"; it uses the [**`TEXT()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TEXT_function) function to format the numeric value to a string thats looks like a date value, and the [**`DATEVALUE()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_DATEVALUE_function) function to create a "real" date value based on the output of TEXT()).*

The result will at first look strange (like 4-16-40 for the date 2014-01-01). Format the field like you normally do: `Format > Cells` and choose `Date` and the proper format.

Comment: Thank you. I edited your answer as the comma in the formula didn't work. It needs a semi colon. Additionaly I gave an example of the confusing result you get.

Comment: @rxt: Argument separators depend on l10n, so it's hard to predict which version (comma or semicolon) suits better in a certain case. Some users may have to use commata, some will need to use semicola. Good idea to give an example for the "strange" result!

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by tohuwawohu. I would suggest this as an alternative:

```
=DATE(QUOTIENT(A1;10000);QUOTIENT(MOD(A1;10000);100);MOD(A1;100))
```

You might want to format the cell after you have applied this formula.